# BVH import gives unexpected armature

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I wrote my own BVH reader and to check my implementation I compared it with the result Blender gives, which confused me. Consider the BVH file from the BVH loader example from three.js (https://threejs.org/examples/?q=bvh#webgl_loader_bvh). This looks like something like this:

[image: BVH file displayed with three.js (see link above)]

Then I loaded the same BVH file into Blender, which looks like this:

[image: BVH file displayed with Blender]

In those pictures you see that the bones are not exactly the same. E.g., in the three.js rendering, the collar bone connects to the chest joint, while in the Blender rendering, the collar bone connects to the neck. Or you could also say that Blender connects the collar joint to the end of the chest bone, while three.js connects it to the start of the chest bone.

To me, the three.js rendering makes more sense, because the definition in the BVH is:

```
ROOT hip
{
  OFFSET 0 0 0
  CHANNELS 6 Xposition Yposition Zposition Zrotation Yrotation Xrotation
  JOINT abdomen
  {
    OFFSET 0 20.6881 -0.73152
    CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
    JOINT chest
    {
      OFFSET 0 11.7043 -0.48768
      CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
      JOINT neck
      {
        ...
      }
      JOINT rCollar
      {
        OFFSET -2.68224 19.2634 -4.8768
        CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
        JOINT rShldr
        ...
```

So, you can see that the right collar joint is a child of the chest, not the neck, so it should be connected to the chest, not the neck.

Similarly, there appears an unexpected bone protruding from the hip in the Blender rendering, even though the hip is the root join in the BVH file, so it shouldn't be a bone.

Additionally, in this example, blender decided that the connection from the root to the right (and left) hip is not a bone but just an offset (dashed line). It made the same decision in a couple of other places, like e.g. around the neck and for the finger joints. I don't understand how this happens.

I realize that those differences don't really matter for the final position of the joints. I'm just trying to understand the BVH file format because I want to convert 3D positions into joint angles and store this as BVH. So those observations I just described confuse me a lot. I guess you could summarize my question as follows: How does Blender define/find a bone and when is a connection between joints not a bone, but just an offset (dashed line in the Blender picture)? Does this happen because the BVH file format is under-specified?

Comment: Where there any messages regarding zero length bones when you imported into blender?

Comment: @batFINGER No, not for the file mentioned in my post. I did notice this however in other files. I figured out that blender takes the average bone length for zero length bones (i.e. when the offset is the zero vector), which I also find kind of peculiar.